# Azure Node web app Entra ID login page redirection problem

Tags: azure, authentication, redirect

I deployed a simple sign in and sign out Node application with Microsoft authentication on Azure. I hope after login with Entra ID, the redirect page can return to home page with user info. However, after login, still the page shows no user info. The application runs fine locally, but not in Azure. I wonder why.

Home page before login: Welcome, please sign in.

Correct home page after login: User name, email.

Wrong home page after login: Welcome, please sign in.

Some code:

```
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const msal = require("@azure/msal-node");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const session = require("express-session");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || "local_default_secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
  })
);

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID}`,
    clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
        console.log(message);
      },
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
      logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
    },
  },
};

const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

function getRedirectUri() {
  return process.env.PROD_REDIRECT_URI;
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", {
    isAuthenticated: req.session.isAuthenticated,
    user: req.session.user || null,
  });
});

app.get("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const authCodeUrlParameters = {
      scopes: ["user.read"],
      redirectUri: getRedirectUri(),
    };
    const loginUrl = await pca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters);
    res.redirect(loginUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Error building auth code URL");
  }
});

app.get("/redirect", async (req, res) => {
  const tokenRequest = {
    code: req.query.code,
    scopes: ["user.read"],
    redirectUri: getRedirectUri(),
  };

  try {
    const response = await pca.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest);
    req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
    req.session.user = jwt.decode(response.accessToken);
    console.log("I am here!");
    res.redirect("/");
    console.log("I am still here!");
    console.log("Session here: ", req.session);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    if (error.name === "ClientAuthError") {
      res.status(401).send("Authentication failed. Please try to login again.");
    } else {
      res.status(500).send("Error acquiring token");
    }
  }
});

app.get("/signout", (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send("Error during sign out.");
    }

    // Determine the post logout redirect URI based on the environment
    const postLogoutRedirectUri = process.env.PROD_URI;

    // Redirect to Azure AD logout URL
    const tenantId = process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID;
    const logoutUri = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=${postLogoutRedirectUri}`;
    res.redirect(logoutUri);
  });
});

const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

In Azure log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJTm3.jpg)

As you can see from above screenshots, the user can be authenticated and the application can get the token and all the user info, and the page should be redirected to homepage with user info. But it never happen in this way.

I hope to figure out why after login, the page cannot correctly show the right information. What can be the cause?

Comment: Can you share the log error in text format.

Answer (score 0):

To handle Azure AD authentication and display user information after successful login, I did with using the `passport` and `passport-azure-ad` libraries to handle the authentication process. It manually manages the session and user authentication state.
The passport-azure-ad package makes it easy to get up and running with Azure AD authentication in your Express application.

**Code:**

```js
//app.js
    const  express  =  require('express'); 
    const  passport  =  require('passport');
    const  OIDCStrategy  =  require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;
    const  app  =  express();
    // Configure session
    app.use(require('express-session')({ secret:  'your-secret-key', resave:  true, saveUninitialized:  true }));
    // Initialize passport
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    // Ensure authenticated middleware
    function  ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return  next();
    }
    res.redirect('/');
    }
    // Configure Azure AD authentication
    passport.use(new  OIDCStrategy({
    identityMetadata:  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    clientID:  'clientID',
    responseType:  'code',
    responseMode:  'query',
    redirectUrl:  'http://localhost:3000/auth/callback',
    allowHttpForRedirectUrl:  true,
    clientSecret:  'clientSecret',
    validateIssuer:  false,  
    passReqToCallback:  false,
    scope: ['openid', 'profile'],
    },
    (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {
    return  done(null, profile);
    }));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) =>  done(null, user));
    passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) =>  done(null, obj));
   
    // Routes
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.send(`Welcome, ${req.user.displayName}! <a href="/logout">Logout</a>`);
    } else {
    res.send('Home Page <a href="/login">Login</a>'); 
    }
    });
    app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect')); 
    app.get('/auth/callback',
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect:  '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/home');
    });
    app.get('/home', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    
    res.send(`Welcome, ${req.user.displayName}! <a href="/logout">Logout</a>`);
    
    });
    app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
    });
    // Start server
    const  PORT  =  process.env.PORT  ||  3000;
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });
```

**Output**

**Local**

[image]

**Deployed to App Service**

[image]

Please refer below MSDoc

[Deploy a Node.js web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode)

[Build and deploy a Node.js web application using Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-express-app)